# changing text in jquery on toggle asp.net

Tags: javascript, toggle

i write a javascript code to toggle a div on click of a link :

```
<a id="show" href="#" class="lnk_log">
   Show Information
</a>
<div id="info_div" style="display:none;">
   sssss 
</div>
```

and the jquery code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show").click(function () {
        if ($("#show").text() == "Show Information") {
            $("#show").text("Hide Information");
            $("#info_div").toggle("slow");
        } else {
            $("#show").text("Show Information");
            $("#info_div").toggle("slow");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

but the problem is the changing of the word (show information,hide information)
when i click on the button is show "show information" and when re-click again it shows "hide information" ... its reverse ... can please find me a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Just change your code from

`<a id="show" href="#" class="lnk_log">
   Show Information
</a>`

To

```
<a id="show" href="#" class="lnk_log">Show Information</a>
```

Comment: its worked for me ...but can u tell why this happened ?

Comment: .text() retrieves text including newlines. So in your previous code it retrieved "'newline' Show Information 'newline'". Then onclick 'if condition' was false, so it executed else condition. which replaces text to only 'Show Information' without new lines. After that your code was running correct, but it was reverse to you. If you want to use previous format only you should use trim() function to remove newlines and unnecessary spaces as suggested by 'Roko C. Buljan'

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/juzine/2/edit)**

Your main issue is that your DIV text has spaces (***newlines***), therefore willl never match your query therefore will trigger the `else`

You have to first **trim your text from whitespaces**:

```
  var $show = $("#show"); // Also, cache the selectors you plan to reuse

  $show.click(function () {
    var showText = $.trim( $show.text() );
    if (showText === "Show Information") {
      $show.text("Hide Information");
    }
    else {
      $show.text("Show Information");
    }
    $("#info_div").toggle("slow");
  });
```

Also, since you use an `anchor` it would be good to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) to prevent the browser jumping to-top. If it's always hidden by default, you can also rewrite your code like:

**[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/juzine/3/edit)**

```
$("#show").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // prevent browser default anchor behavior
    $(this).text( ((this.tog^=1)?"Hide":"Show") +" Information" );
    $("#info_div").toggle("slow");
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault